# Is it "finger clicking" or "finger snapping"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Is it "finger clicking"?
What verb should I use if not "click"? "Snap"? Are both ok? It's just that if I say "finger snapping", one may imagine something violent.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's neither. The expression is "to snap one's fingers".  For example: "If you snap your fingers at the waiter, he will spit in your soup"

Comment: One **finger** does not a clicking make.... And when we mention body parts it's common to use determiners such as my, your, his e.g "if you're happy and you know it, click your fingers"

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/snap-click-your-fingers

Comment: No one will imagine something violent when you say *finger snapping*, because *snapping fingers* is a common idiom.

Comment: @stangdon but it could also mean breaking someone's fingers (i.e. "snapping" them)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev  It *could*, but my point is that nobody is likely to interpret it that way, because it is an established idiom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes "snap your fingers" is the common phrase, but "clicking" is also an alternative. The image you searched was even labelled as "finger snapping"!

> **Snapping (or clicking) one's fingers** is the act of creating a snapping or clicking sound with one's fingers. Primarily this is done by building tension between the thumb and another (middle, index, or ring) finger and then moving the other finger forcefully downward, so it hits the palm of the same hand at a high speed. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_snapping)

Answer (score 2):

*to snap one's fingers* is the common phrase. It has nothing to do with digital mayhem; rather it means to produce a snap sound with the fingers, as if by breaking a twig.
I think the actual sound is produced by one of the fingers slapping against the meaty part of the palm under the thumb after the finger is held under tension and then suddenly released.